# WooCommerce Search Function issue

Tags: wordpress, search, woocommerce

I have an issue with the WooCommerce product search. I tried different search plugins and the native WordPress search, but this problem occurs on all of them.

The issue:

If I search for a word, for example "Zahnkranz" and type into the input field "Zahn" it finds the products:

[image]

So far so good.

Soon as I type the complete word "Zahnkranz", it doesn't suggest any products and also dotn show any products on the result page:

[image]

[image]

I tried:

- Cleaning the database
- testing different search plugins
- reindexing the products via search plugin

Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Try searching with uppercase. In second screenshot you search with lowercase.

Comment: @Snuffy no difference.. But if I type Zahn kranz, it finds the products - weird as hell, since the product title contains no space

Comment: By default, WordPress uses a SQL query with the LIKE operator, which performs a case-insensitive search with a wildcard % before and after the search term.  You have to change the sql query to your needs. Also its searching in title and description for words so keep that in mind too.

Comment: @Snuffy in my case i use for example a search plugin for WooCommerce. In the settings the search for title, categories, short description and SKU is enabled. So long description. So it searched through all that tables. Also, the search rule "%s% ( contains ). Search query can be inside any part of the product words ( beginning, end, middle ). Slow."

But anyway, even if I use a different plugin or the native search its the same outcome